# antonym of "supple" in "supple skin"?

Tags: antonyms

What is an antonym of "supple" in "supple skin"?

From Merriam-Webster online dictionary, I saw the antonyms of "supple" are "    inflexible, rigid, stiff, stiffened". I don't think these antonyms are proper to describe skin.

So what is the antonym of "supple" in "supple skin"?

Comment: In the context of skin, the opposite of *supple* isn't so much *inflexible, rigid, stiff, stiffened*. It's more a matter of being ***inelastic***. If you pinch a fold of skin up on the back of an old person's hand, then let go, it remains "peaked up" much longer than the same fold of *supple skin* on a younger person's hand.

Comment: *stiff* it is; *inflexible* and *inelastic* are similar, too. A stiff skin does not stretch and 'resile' easily.

Comment: Rough skin (on hands, knees and elbows) and dry skin (generally on face).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Stiff** seems to be a more clinical term. (I have never heard of anyone's skin described that way in normal conversation.)

More clinical terms can be found in this article:

> [Stiff skin syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_skin_syndrome) (also known as "Congenital fascial
>   dystrophy") is a cutaneous condition characterized by ‘rock hard’
>   induration, thickening of the skin and subcutaneous tissues, ...

**Leathery**

In a discussion on aging skin, [this article](http://www.drnorthrup.com/womenshealth/healthcenter/topic_details.php?topic_id=52) includes the following:

> Cross-linking of the naturally **supple** collagen molecules makes them
>   become stiff and inflexible, eventually resulting in skin that looks
>   and feels “old and **leathery**.”

While *leathery* is not the literal antonym of *supple*, it does appear to be a polar opposite of *supple* in terms of skin quality. And even though the article is written by a medical doctor describing skin in clinical terms, *leathery skin* is also a commonly used expression.

By the way, here is an interesting site, called [Words To Use](http://www.words-to-use.com/words/skin/), showing a long list of adjectives to go with "skin".

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion,
supple in "supple skin" means silky skin.
So antonym is rough.